# Storing dynamic dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-storage

I wish to store if a specific date is loaded via Javascript. How this boolean is saved/accessed has no difference, however I'm not sure as to what the best solution is performance-wise.

I could know I could store it like this and loop through each object, however I guess this wouldn't really be efficient.
    `var loaded = { {d:23, m:11, y:2012}, {d:24, m:11, y:2012} };`

Another idea I have is to store this in an array, like so:
    `loaded[2012][11][23] = true;`

But I'm sure there are better ways to accomplish this, so I'd appreciate any guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have to list available years, available months or available days, you could always use an Object as a dictionary for storing dates as UNIX timestamp numbers (which you can convert to and from Date objects) or "YYYYMMDD" strings.